# bower ENOTFOUND Package videogular not found

Tags: angularjs, bower, videogular

I am trying to install *videogular* using *bower* and I am getting the error:

```
bower ENOTFOUND     Package videogular not found
```

**Should I install in manually?**

Answer (score 1):

We've been deleted this week the bower package to create a new one, sorry about this, we will try to have it again running very soon (probably this weekend).

Meanwhile you can download it manually through this repo: https://github.com/2fdevs/bower-videogular

Comment: Fixed, now you can install `videogular` using `bower` with `bower install videogular` :)